Door 1 x 3 x 1 with left / right indication
Part 3821 exists since 1978.
I am looking for the first date or set when the doors with L / R indication where released.

This part (32ac01 Door 1 x 2 x 3 Hinge on Left with Solid Studs and Fixed Glass) is a door with a clear left indication, released in 1954:

Is this what you are looking for? (See also the right counterpart)
In case the search should be restricted to openable doors, then the oldest is 445 Door 1 x 3 x 4 Left from 1967:

